# creating a view that a logged in user is able to search another persons username to view his profile

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

#### Routes

Routes for profile and image upload:

```
 Route::get('profile', 'UserController@profile');
 //route to the users profile
 Route::post('profile', 'UserController@update_avatar');
```

Route to the profile viewer that I want to create:

```
 Route::get('/view', 'UserController@getView');
```

#### UserController

My profile logic. for avatar upload

```
public function profile()
{
    return view('profile', array('user'=> Auth::user()) );
}

public function update_avatar(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time().'.'. $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)
            ->save(public_path("/uploads/avatars/$filename"));

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }

    return view('profile', array('user'=> Auth::user()));
}

// getView function, I have no idea what to put here
public function getView()
{
    return view('view', array('user'=> Auth::user()));
}
```

My profile view in `views.blade.php`:
   I need this to be shown when a user needs to view another profile

```
<section>  
    <div class="mbr-box mbr-section mbr-section--relative mbr-section--fixed-size mbr-section--full-height mbr-section--bg-adapted mbr-parallax-backgroundr">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="width:800px; height:700px; border-radius:10px; float:left; padding-top:15px; margin-left:20px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{$user->avatar}}" style= "padding-top:15px; width:150px; float:left; height:150px; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;"> 
                            <h2>{{$user-> name }}'s Profile from {{$user->city}}</h2>

                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="POST" id="hover">

                                <label>update profile image</label>
                                <input type="file" name="avatar">
                                <input type="hidden" name ="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn-sm btn-default" value="Send Picture">
                            </form><br/>

                            <h1 style="font:sans serif, Helvitica; color:#d1d5d5;"> Taking  {{$user->course}} </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: the concept of actually creating that view 'view' to view another users' profile  @Ross

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers. Essentially you use the id (or other unique identifier) of the user to load them up and then you pass them through to your view.